# Listing trash bin contents showing as empty

Tags: python, macos

I definitely have placed some files in my trash bin on my Mac but for some reason my code is printing an empty array `[]` - here is my code in my python file:

```
import os
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
from datetime import datetime
import shutil

bin_location = "/Users/nick/.Trash"
bin_files = os.listdir(bin_location)

for f in bin_files:
    print(f)

print(os.listdir('/Users/nick/.Trash'))
```

I’m using VSCode and have given permission in my system settings to allow the program to access the .Trash directory (to fix a permissions error I initially had). Is there something obvious that I’m doing wrong? I cannot see why it is not listing the files in the bin.

Comment: I don't know about Mac OS, but on Linux, the trash is on a virtual file system. It might be something similar on Mac.

Comment: I just tried this on my Mac and it listed the files in my trash just fine. However, keep in mind that the Trash you see in the Finder merges trashes from all volumes, so if you trashed a file from an external drive then it will not be in `~/.Trash`.

Comment: I trashed a local file on my MacBook and not from an external drive so I assume this should show, right?

Comment: @user8758206 Is the file you trashed on the same volume as your user folder?

Comment: yeah it is on the same volume

Comment: @user8758206 Try opening the Trash in the Finder, dragging the file from there to a Terminal window, and see what path it pastes in. (You could also right-click on the file, then hold Option and choose Copy [filename] as Pathname.)